# ASP.NET handling two different login forms on the same device

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, cookies

I have two different login pages in my `asp.net` website. One for sellers and one for customers. I use `FormsAuthentication` to authenticate users in both pages.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Username, false);
```

I also use `FormsAuthenticationTicket` if user selects the Remember Me checkbox.

Now my problem is when a seller also registers as a  customer and wants to login as a customer he will be logged out from his seller account. What should I do? Can I have two different login cookies on the same browser without any conflict?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Adding a unique session name..!!??

Comment: @too_cool How long does a session last? 20 mins? I think we have to set it as a permament cookie then. And I have to check this session in every single page? And what happens when a user wants to logout from one of them? both will be logged out.

Comment: What is the underlying problem of a user being both a Seller and a Customer at the same time?  Conceptually it is 2 roles for a single user account, and should be pretty simple to handle.  Is there a specific task that you're stuck on?  Is your architecture stuck on this not being feasible?  I'd suggest if they register as a Customer you add a role to their existing Seller Account and not create a whole new account.

Comment: @AdamHeeg I have two different tables for customer and seller in database and I check sellers' role by querying seller's table. Is there a simple way to assign role to a user just to identify if he's customer or seller?

Comment: @PayamSh Create 3 tables: Users, Roles, User_Roles.  User logs in with their name and password which is in the Users Table, then you query all their assigned roles in User_Roles and add a list or roles and maybe a public read only property IsCustomer, IsSeller which you can then do easy checks against in your pages.